# Catching 'external drive inserted' event in a windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services, podcast

I'm trying to write a super-simple podcast-to-device downloading service to use for running.  I imagine that it'll like this:

Whenever a particular device is plugged in (via USB), it:

- Deletes everything from the device
- Checks for all the latest entries in a number of RSS Podcast feeds
- Downloads those to the device
- Notifies the user about when its done.

I have some passing experience with windows services, but am not sure how to (using .NET/C#) catch the 'media device/usb hard drive has been plugged in' event.  Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to periodically enumerate the devices!

CodeProject has a comprehensive C# article for this here : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/DriveDetector.aspx